# How to run unit tests for code that uses App Engine services in Go?

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, go

I was told the best solution to run unit tests for code that uses App Engine services such as datastore or memcache was to run the development server in a child process, but I'm not sure how. Anybody successfully ran this kind of test and can share a solution?

App Engine SDK for Go uses the Python dev_appserver; [see this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-go/msg/d0cb913f1f03155c).

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a "unit test"? Mine is testing a single class in isolation. That means you're using special mock objects for all other services and classes used by the class under test.

Comment: I need, for example, to check the response of given handlers that use datastore or memcache. I don't want to mock the whole datastore or all other services implementations for this, because this would be a pretty huge and insane task. So I need to use the underlying stubs implemented in dev_appserver.py.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out [Google App Engine Go testing library](https://github.com/icub3d/appenginetesting) by Josh Marsh.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. It appeared after this question was posted. :)

Answer (score 6):

An interesting development, as of 1.8.6 using service stubs has been integrated into the SDK through the `"appengine/aetest"` package. [More info](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/localunittesting)

Answer (score 1):

I know the questioner wants to build a testbed and needs to do this, but I think there's another approach worth mentioning here.

Besides using a testbed for the GAE services, Go's interesting nature also opens up another possibility: write your application to just require objects that have the interfaces that you use (they'd be a subset of the official APIs) and mock them out when testing. This requires you to be doing some amount of dependency injection of some sort, but that's a really good idea anyway.

Once the interfaces the interfaces are written, you can mock them using a library like [gomock](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/gomock/gomock).