# How to run unit tests for appengine go project

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have my appengine SDK in ~/Applications/google_appengine

In Eclipse, i've got an external tool setup to run the dev server. It's pointed at:

~/Application/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py

Also in Eclipse (Go Preferences), I've set the GOROOT to point to

~/Application/google_appengine/goroot

Now, I'm trying to run some unit tests for my project. If I use my regular go installation (not the appengine one), I get this error:

```
../../context/context.go:4:2: cannot find package "appengine" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/appengine (from $GOROOT)
/Users/home/src/go/foodbox/src/appengine (from $GOPATH)
../../context/data.go:4:2: cannot find package "appengine/datastore" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/appengine/datastore (from $GOROOT)
/Users/home/src/go/foodbox/src/appengine/datastore (from $GOPATH)
../../context/context.go:5:2: cannot find package "appengine/user" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/pkg/appengine/user (from $GOROOT)
/Users/home/src/go/foodbox/src/appengine/user (from $GOPATH)
```

If i use the appengine go, I get this one:

```
load cmd/cgo: package cmd/cgo: no Go source files in /Users/home/Application/google_appengine/goroot/src/cmd/cgo
```

It seems like the default installation can't find the appengine packages (I guess that's not surprising). I'm not sure what the problem is when I use the appengine go tools. Can anyone tell me how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858711/how-to-run-unit-tests-for-code-that-uses-app-engine-services-in-go (especially https://github.com/icub3d/appenginetesting)

Comment: So there's no way to use go tools out of the box to test an appengine application? Theoretically, I should be able to create interface wrappers around appengine specific libraries. Can I not do this?

Comment: If you want to write interface wrappers arounnd appengine specific libraries see -- https://github.com/crhym3/aegot  It's not something I'd recommend as you'll be stubbing a LOT

Answer (score 5):

It may be worth mentioning that the `appengine/aetest` package is now included in the SDK, [since 1.8.6](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForGoReleaseNotes). See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/localunittesting).

Basically you get an `appengine.Context` that can be used in your tests, similar to [icub3d/appenginetesting](https://github.com/icub3d/appenginetesting).

Quoting the example from the docs:

```
import (
        "testing"

        "appengine/aetest"
)

func TestMyFunction(t *testing.T) {
        c, err := aetest.NewContext(nil)
        if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer c.Close()

        // Run code and tests requiring the appengine.Context using c.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the docs:

http://blog.golang.org/appengine-dec2013

Check out the section called "Local Unit Testing"

I think what you are looking for is `goapp test` that comes with the sdk.